# I cannot add WIFI drivers to Microsft Deployment Toolkit

Tags: wds, deployment, mdt

I am using Microsoft Deployment Toolkit on Windows Server 2012 to create a deployment image for Windows 7 Home Premium (64 Bit).

I have successfully been able to import most drivers for my Asus K55A laptop however, I am having issues with the WLAN driver. The driver which I am using is the Azurewave Wireless Lan Driver from the ASUS website.

Firstly, I download the driver and extract it (to a folder called WLAN_Atheros_Win7_64_Z920458). 
Next, I open MDT and then select 'Import Drivers' from a folder within the 'Out-of-Box Drivers' dropdown. This launches a wizard which prompts me to select the source of the INF files. I click next and then it says "The process completed sucessfully".

Below is the log:

> Scanning directories for the count of INFs to import. Expanding CAB
>   file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\Desktop\WLAN_Atheros_Win7_64_Z920458\data1.cab
>   Expanding CAB file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\AppData\Local\Temp\2\data1.cab.extract\data1.cab
>   Expanding CAB file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\Desktop\WLAN_Atheros_Win7_64_Z920458\data2.cab
>   Expanding CAB file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\AppData\Local\Temp\2\data2.cab.extract\data2.cab
>   Expanding CAB file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\Desktop\WLAN_Atheros_Win7_64_Z920458\test\data1.cab
>   Expanding CAB file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\AppData\Local\Temp\2\data1.cab.extract\data1.cab
>   Expanding CAB file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\Desktop\WLAN_Atheros_Win7_64_Z920458\test\data2.cab
>   Expanding CAB file
>   C:\Users\Administrator.MCCOSKERS\AppData\Local\Temp\2\data2.cab.extract\data2.cab
>   Performing operation "import" on Target "Out-of-box drivers". Import
>   processing finished.

Lastly, I click "Finish" and then I expect to see the files in my folder in MDT however, it is empty. No such drivers were imported. I refresh and ever close and then reopen MDT but I still cannot see any driver files.

Comment: InstallShield installer and not naked drivers. Non-standard CAB files, contents usually extracted to a temporary directory someplace during install.

Comment: Can you get the "raw" `INF` files and try those? `Cab` files usually do not do what I need them to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Elliot Labs pointed out, you need the INF driver files. You may be able to find these from the C:\Windows\System32\Drivers folder on a computer with the driver installed. Try searching for ath*, many Atheros drivers begin with these letters.

You could also deploy the driver as an application, the command line for silent installation seems to be supplied in the setup.cmd file provided with the downloaded drivers.